# Socket programming, check entry UDP buffer is empty or not?

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, mingw

I'm writing a UDP client that sends a string to a server, when the server sends back several packets, the behavior of the program is not as my expectation. I want to process any incoming packet by `process()` **one by one** until the entry buffer gets empty, but I think there is a problem related to blocking behavior of `recv`.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <winsock.h>

using namespace std;

void process(const char *in, int size)
{
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", in);
}

int main()
{
    char quack_addr[] = "127.0.0.1";
    unsigned short quack_port = 9091;

    WSAData data;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &data);

    sockaddr_in qserver;
    qserver.sin_family = AF_INET;
    qserver.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(quack_addr);
    qserver.sin_port = htons(quack_port);
    SOCKET client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

    if (client <= 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error - Can not create socket.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (true)
    {
        const int MAX = 1024;
        char sbuf[MAX];
        char rbuf[MAX];

        fprintf(stdout, ": ");
        fgets(sbuf, MAX, stdin);
        int slen = strlen(sbuf);

        int r = sendto(client,sbuf,slen,0,(sockaddr*)&qserver,sizeof(qserver));

        // Current code:
        // int rlen = recv(client, rbuf, MAX, 0);
        // if (rlen > 0)
        // {
        //     rbuf[rlen] = 0;
        //     process(rbuf, rlen);
        // }

        // Question starts here:
        //
        // While there is data in queue do:
        // {
        //    (break if there is no data)
        //    int rlen = recv(client, rbuf, MAX, 0);
        //    rbuf[rlen] = 0;
        //    process(rbuf, rlen);
        // }   
    }

    return 0;
}
```

How can I check if the buffer is empty or not, before calling `recv(...)` ?

The problem occurs in this scenario:

1. User is typing a command in the client program (`cmd1`).
2. Simultaneously, the server sends 3 packets to client (`pkt1`, `pkt2`, `pkt3`).
3. After pressing `Enter` in the client side, I expect to receive those 3 packets and probably the result corresponding to `cmd1`, and `process()` all of them one by one.
4. But after pressing `Enter` in stage 3, I receive `pkt1`! and after sending another command to the server I will receive `pkt2` and so on ...!

**I know my code is not enough to handle this issue, so, my question is how to handle it?**

*Note: I'm using `netcat -L -p 9091 -u` as UDP server*

Comment: Do you know how may packages server should send back for your request?

Comment: One version of what I think you want should work as follows:

Comment: (1) uncomment to question starts here

Comment: (3) add line using recvfrom() with flag MSG_PEEK

Comment: (4) add line checking if buffer is empty, aka, if you read anything with (3)

Comment: (5) if yes, break; if no, fall through to loop

Comment: (6) I'm still not 100% sure i understand what exactly you try to do, and am walking while typing this, but this should implement my understanding of your goals

Comment: I forgot if there's a socket command for that (probably). However, you can just resize it to 0, then back to a size you want it to have. I mention the resize buffer command someplace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problems (unsatisfying behavior you do not describe) come from a different source. Let me just list some ideas and comments c./ what was said before:

(1) recvfrom() blocks too. However, you want to use it. Your communication currently sends and receives from loopback, which is fine for your toy program (but: see below). When receiving UDP data, with recv() you don't know who sent it, as the socket was never connect()ed. Use recvfrom() to prepare yourself for some minimal error checking in a more serious program

(2) as select() suspends the program to i/o availibity, it would only put any issue with your socket blocking to a different level. But this is not the problem

(3) to check is the receive buffer is empty, use flag MSG_PEEK in recvfrom() in an appropriate position. It's usually only used to deal with scarce memory, but it should do the job.

(4) reason 1 why I believe you see the issues you don't describe in more detail:
UDP datagrams preserve message boundaries. This means that recvfrom() will read in an entire chunk of data making up any message sent. However, if the buffer you read this into is smaller than the data read, any surplus will be silently discarded. So make sure you have a big buffer (65k something ideally).

(5) reason 2: 
You receive any data sent to the loopback. If you're currently also connected to some net (sat, the Internet), what you catch might actually be from a different source than you expect. So at least in a resting phase, disconnect.

Blocking shouldn't be an issue. Your basic logic, when coded cleanly, is:
Recvfrom() (block/wait until ready)
Process
Peek if buffer empty
Exit if yes
Loop back to receive more if not,

and you seem to want to do this currently. As you don't multi-thread, optimize fie perfiormance, or similar, you shouldn't care about blocking. If you find your receive buffer too small, increase its size using

Setsockopt() for optName SO_RCVBUF

Comment: +1: Thnx. I updated the question and wrote the problem in a scenario. It describes my real problem. However your answer is very useful for me.

Comment: (1) Can you update your actual code too? (eg, the process loop is only sketched)

Comment: (2) describe the order a bit more precisely: "simultaneously" probably can't be, as you probably operate the server and client manually. I am unfamiliar with the server you use, but assume it is meant to echo back your message. But what do you do first, second, etc - eg, tell the server to send three messages, then start your client program and type in/hit enter?

Comment: Actual code for client: remove first commented block. and for server: i noted, i'm using `netcat`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`select()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (with a suitable timeout) to check for incoming data prior to calling `recv()`.

Something like the following (nonportable code)

```
#include <winsock2.h>

...

/* somewhere after your sendto, or your first recv */
fd_set recv_set;
timeval tv = {1, 0}; /* one second */
FD_ZERO(&recv_set);
FD_SET(client, &recv_set);
while (select(0, &recv_set, NULL, NULL, &tv) > 0)
{
    /* recv... */
    FD_SET(client, &recv_set); /* actually redundant, since it is already set */
}
```

Comment: I updated my tags, i'm using mingw and i have problem with O_NONBLOCK because it's not exists in my header files. and i'm not familiar with `select()`, can you show me a good practice for it?

Comment: I missed that this is Winsock, updating answer to match

Comment: +1: I'm using it now, thnx. but it has some issues. After receiving result from server it have to wait until timeout exceeds, and this is bad. And i do not want `break` the `while` after `process()`.

Comment: @MasoudM.: The example is merely that. You will want to modify it to your criteria, eg. shortening the timeout after receiving some data.

Comment: On Windows, instead of `O_NONBLOCK`, you set non-blocking mode using `ioctlsocket` and `FIONBIO`.  Some functions, like `WSAAsyncSelect` set non-blocking mode automatically.

Answer (score 1):

iPhone sometimes bugs out and doesn't let me post comments. Thanks, Steve. This is just continuing the conversation.

I assume this means 'uncomment to 'question starts here'. Partial answer, as this still depends on my 2nd comment; this is more or less than what to expect. Assuming the three messages to be sent by the server are already queued up, after you hit enter for the first time, your packet is sent (never blocked as sendto() doesn't block for UDP), received by the server and (I assume, see above, echoed back and added to the FIFO receive buffer in which you alread have three messages queued up. You then have a recv() in your program which receives the first queued up message, printing it out. Your current logic goes back to top of loop, expect another input and waits for it (so this isn't blocked on a socket level, but as your program requests input, eg simply 'enter'), then comes to the second originally sent message (by the server) and processes that one. One more loop, and all three are done. Hitting enter again, and assuming the server echoes what you sent, you should start receiving your typed in messages (which might be empty if you only hit enter). The loop will currently not exit except you kill it.

Comment: Again, this assumes you are not connected to the Internet or other UDP datagrams might show up; and that you operate in the order implied ny what I just wrote.

Comment: If it's at all like the Android app, what happens is that after posting one comment, the add comment link/button is hidden.  So you can't split a lengthy message into multiple comments :(